# Debugging prospective search possible false negatives

Tags: google-app-engine

I have Prospective Search sucessfully (hopefully) setup with my app, and it is really cool.

But there are some documents which I would expect to have matched at the time when they were received, and they didn't.

So, now I am trying to debug this, but I can't find any log traces left by prospective search to see why they didn't match. In fact, the only place I can add some logging calls are on my match result handler, but that one is only called when there is a positive match. That only lets me debug False positives, but I can't find how to debug False negatives (documents that didn't find a match, and I believe they should).

The problem is a bit strange, because if I call match right now on that document, there are match results, but there were none at the time. I am reasonably confident that the subscriptions haven't changed.

I know that prospective search works perfectly, I am totally confident that it is my fault either because of a wrong Document or a wrong query, but I just would like to have some way to see where and how I am screwing things up.

Any tips, clues, ideas, suggestions, etc?

EDIT: In this case, my problem had to do with how I had setup taskqueues. The final result being that prospective search was creating taskqueues that are being dropped because the backend is returning 503's and after a number of retries. But still, I felt there are not enough tools/traces to debug problems with prospective search queries/documents.

Comment: Payala, thanks for sharing your expirience. Can I ask how many queries do you have? Would it work if I have over 12M queries? How fast matched ids would appear on task queue? I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Alexander, sorry, but it's been more than a year since this question. The project isn't even live anymore, so I'm afraid I can't answer your questions accurately. I think I had around 10K queries run several times per hour. I don't know about speed anyway, in my site other things were limiting the speed of processing the matches.

Comment: Did you find the solution?  If so, can you post it here and accept as a self answer so this question may be considered resolved?